# How to implement one-to-one communication in MQTT?

Tags: protocols, mqtt, iot

I am trying to set up a MQTT system for a project that connects many clients.

These clients are of different type and may have different functionality. Some client-types have information - like temperature - which is being published but at the same time feature states that need to be set - like switches - which can be set by other clients.

So using MQTT I came up with the following concept:

1. The client publishes the informations it has - in the above example this would be the temperature, so like:

   customer/group/device/temperature
2. When the client connects to a broker, in order to receive a state for the switch from different clients it subscribes to:

   customer/group/device/switch

I have been using a websocket based solution so far but since MQTT is a famous protocol for IoT devices I was asking myself how to implement one to one communications between clients and came up with the above example of how I would do that.

Comment: MQTT topics should not start with a /, this just adds a null element to the tree and makes things harder later

Comment: You've asked and answered your own question here between the title and the body of the "question". What response are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is pretty OK. For example, client `A` can publish to client `B` using topic `customer/group/B/switch`, then client `B` replies to `customer/group/A/switch`.

As an alternative, client `A` can publish to `customer/group/B/switch` and specify in the payload the topic where it expects replies, for example

```
{
    "data":"your message",
    "reply-to":"customer/group/A/segretreply-fromB-1345313"
}
```

(just an example of JSON payload).
You can use timestamps, MACs or other sources of "uniqueness" to build the reply-to topic. Client `A` could subscribe to different reply-to topics to mantain "separate" channels for each other client.

The real problem is that MQTT **is not a one-to-one** communication, each client can, potentially, subscribe to `#` and receive all messages.
You should have some sort of **authorization** in your broker to decide whether a client can publish/subscribe to a topic or not.

I suggest reading this excellent article [MQTT Security Fundamentals: Authorization](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-security-fundamentals-authorization). Then you can setup topics and authorization rules to better fit your requirements.

I'm not affiliated with HiveMQ. The link provided is just for educational purposes, their tutorial are great.